# Numeration in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

please have at look on my issue.

I try to assign a autonumber with increment plus 1 for each new record in [No] as integer.
I use following code, but it doesn`t works correctly, and records stops calculated.

```
Private Sub Ser_AfterUpdate()
If Ser = "O" Then
    Dim MyYear, varLast
        MyYear = Year(Date)
        Yr = Right(MyYear, 2)
        varLast = DLast("No", "NotamT")
        No = varLast + 1
        Types.Requery
    Else
    MsgBox "WRONG NOTAM SERIES"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Use an `Autonumer` field which will increment automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not very clear, what you try to do, but it could be something like this:

```vb
Private Sub Ser_AfterUpdate()

    If Ser = "O" Then
        Me!Yr.Value = Year(Date) Mod 100
        Me!No.Value = Nz(DMax("No", "NotamT")) + 1
        Me!Types.Requery
    Else
        MsgBox "WRONG NOTAM SERIES"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: each of my records has numeric value, for instance 0001 for first record and 0002 for second one...

Comment: Sorry, lost the `Date` ... corrected.